# Get Destination Ip/Port of active udp Connection?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi, windows-networking

I m able to retrieved active TCP and UDP connection using iphlpapi.
The TCP Connection showing with source info(ip/port), Destination info(ip/port), state and process id. 
But for UDP Connection its no giving remote IP and port. That what i want to get.
Any way to get destination information using source information or process id in Delphi or c++.

Comment: Are you writing an app like netstat?

Comment: UDP is connectionless -- so the only way to see the remote IP/Port is to capture the packets.  Are you sure you're not looking at a UDP listener?

Comment: @afrazier.. No I'm not looking for Udp listener. I'll try packet capture. Any Help for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP is a connectionless protocol. You can only get the local port that has been opened.

UPDATE:
This applies for a static look at the port usage. However, if you have active UDP trafic you can still retrieve the remote endpoint.

User Ishmeet suggested uIP or LwIP in the comments.

[UDP - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)

[Connectionless Protocol - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionless_protocol)

Comment: No, you can get the IP address, I have done this on uIP, also on LwIP, on the callback function you receive the IP address and port number from the packet received

Comment: OK, I agree... if you have active traffic you can get the senders endpoint. But the simple port usage information is not enough.

Comment: void udp_recv(struct udp_pcb * pcb,
               void (* recv)(void * arg, struct udp_pcb * upcb,
                                         struct pbuf * p,
                                         struct ip_addr * addr,
                                         u16_t port),
               void * recv_arg)

-->http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/Raw/UDP