# Remote address of active UDP connections in Windows using IP Helper

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winapi, iphelper

The function [GetUdpTable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudptable) in [IP Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/IpHlp/ip-helper-start-page) returns a table of [MIB_UDPROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/udpmib/ns-udpmib-_mib_udprow).

`MIB_UDPROW` struct does not contain any information about the remote address of the UDP connection, the extended variants of `GetUdpTable()` only adds the `pid` to the return struct.

Is it possible to get the remote address for an active UDP connection using IP Helper (or any other winapi)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get the remote port of the UDP connection unless you capture traffic and inspect the packets since UDP is a connectionless protocol.

See: [Get Destination Ip/Port of active udp Connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745971/get-destination-ip-port-of-active-udp-connection)